# Change button on click()

Tags: onclick, ionic-framework

I am trying to change my button icon, thext and want to disable onClick().

Unfortunateley it changes the text when I first click and when I click again it changes the icon but does not disbale it.

In the stack the varaibles are set correctly after the click event.
I really dont know why it does not work and why it changes when I click twice.

Here is my html:

```
<ion-view title="Who-U">
    <ion-content class="padding">

        <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#">
            <img src="img/cover.png">
            <h2>{{username}}</h2>
            <p>Points: {{points}}</p>
        </a>

        <button ng-click="click()" class="button button-full button-positive" ng-disabled="{{buttonDisable}}">
            <i class='{{buttonType}}'></i>{{text}}
        </button>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thats my controller:

```
angular.module('home', ['services'])

.controller('homeCtrl',
    function ($scope, $location, $state, localStorageService, serverAPI, $ionicPopup) {

       $scope.buttonType = "icon ion-search",
        $scope.buttonDisable = false,
        $scope.text = 'Search',


        $scope.click = function () {
            $scope.buttonDisable = true
            $scope.text = 'Searching'
            $scope.buttonType = "icon ion-loading-a"

        };

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You forget to put ';' in your code :p

Try this :

```
   $scope.buttonType = "icon ion-search";
    $scope.buttonDisable = false;
    $scope.text = 'Search';


    $scope.click = function () {
        $scope.buttonDisable = true;
        $scope.text = 'Searching';
        $scope.buttonType = "icon ion-loading-a";
}
```